# Can you patch apk this way?

Tags: android, apk, patch

first sorry for this stupid question but i'm new to this and trying to learn

i have Android App
i did patch the apk to bypass SSL Pinning using apk-mitm
https://github.com/shroudedcode/apk-mitm

i used BurpSuite to do some modification to request body for some of what the app can and can't send and everything works just fine

now is there is any method to patch this APK with these Rules i made and i don't have to run BurpSuite every time i run the App ?

Comment: Sounds suspicious to be honest :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you have linux you have the methods but as android needs jdk you must compile and regenerate apk. If you know about manual editing. You can do it by repackaging. If you don't you should pay for security application(BurpSuite) for advanced access.